# Target only one ID (or class) from several buttons on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, target

How can I target the one button that I clicked and not the other buttons with the same ID or Class in the same page?

Thanks!!

## HTML (Slim code)

```
.dropdown
    button.dropbtn
        = cta_copy1
    #myDropdown.dropdown-content
        a href="#home" Women
        a href="#about" Men
        a href="#contact" Kids
```

## JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function ctaDropMenu() {
      document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    $(".dropbtn").click(ctaDropMenu);

    // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: `not the other buttons with the same ID ` this is scary !! IDs must be unique

Comment: [FIDDLEJS] (https://jsfiddle.net//neuhaus3000/jf1zetLw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jf1zetLw/3/)**.

First The `id` attribute should be unique in the same document, instead you could use the common classes.

I'm not sure why you're mixing the vanillaJs with the jQuery code but if you want to target the related `.dropdown-content` or `#myDropdown` (if it's unique) you could use :

```
$(this).closest('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-content').toggleClass('show');
```

You event could be simple like :

```
$(".dropbtn").on('click', function(){
  var current_dropdown = $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-content');

  $('.dropdown-content').not(current_dropdown).removeClass('show');
  current_dropdown.toggleClass('show');
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(".dropbtn").on('click', function(){
  var current_dropdown = $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-content');

  $('.dropdown-content').not(current_dropdown).removeClass('show');
  current_dropdown.toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  width: 200px;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: $secondary;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #002b54;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 99;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #002b54;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-family: $secondary;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.show { 
  display:block; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Click Me</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Click Me</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't he want 'removeClass' since subsiquent clicks to the dom would add the 'show' class back to those elements if he used toggleClass?

Comment: I'm not sure why using the other click event on the `window` but i'm just trying to point him to the use of the current clicked object `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using this,which refers to current element in DOM
lets we have the following buttons

```
    <button name="btn1" class="btn">Btn1</button>
<button name="btn2" class="btn">Btn2</button>
<button name="btn3" class="btn">Btn3</button>
<button name="btn4" class="btn">Btn4</button>
```

your JavaScript code will be like

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.btn').click(function(){
            alert(this.name);
        })
   });
```

This example will alert the current name of button having same class. I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass a reference to the event in your function.

```
function ctaDropMenu(event) {
  var target = $(event.currentTarget);
  target.toggleClass("show");
}

$(".dropbtn").click(ctaDropMenu);
```

This should do the trick for you.